# Illegal start of expression error: errors with two lines?

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors

I am working on a school coding project as a beginner. The code I have written is messy and not styled great, but this is how I understand how to write it. I am left with 18 errors on only three lines and can not figure out where I am going wrong. Here are my errors:

```
Band.java:42: illegal start of expression
    private static void calculate (int numberRows, double[][] positions, int[] rowNumber, double total) {
    ^

Band.java:42: illegal start of expression
    private static void calculate (int numberRows, double[][] positions, int[] rowNumber, double total) {
            ^

Band.java:42: ';' expected
    private static void calculate (int numberRows, double[][] positions, int[] rowNumber, double total) {
                  ^

Band.java:42: '.class' expected
    private static void calculate (int numberRows, double[][] positions, int[] rowNumber, double total) {
                                       ^

Band.java:42: ';' expected
    private static void calculate (int numberRows, double[][] positions, int[] rowNumber, double total) {
                                                 ^

Band.java:42: <identifier> expected
    private static void calculate (int numberRows, double[][] positions, int[] rowNumber, double total) {
                                                                        ^

Band.java:42: illegal start of expression
    private static void calculate (int numberRows, double[][] positions, int[] rowNumber, double total) {
                                                                            ^

Band.java:42: ';' expected
    private static void calculate (int numberRows, double[][] positions, int[] rowNumber, double total) {
                                                                             ^

Band.java:42: not a statement
    private static void calculate (int numberRows, double[][] positions, int[] rowNumber, double total) {
                                                                               ^

Band.java:42: ';' expected
    private static void calculate (int numberRows, double[][] positions, int[] rowNumber, double total) {
                                                                                        ^

Band.java:42: ';' expected
    private static void calculate (int numberRows, double[][] positions, int[] rowNumber, double total) {
                                                                                                      ^

Band.java:85: 'else' without 'if'
                    } else {
                      ^

Band.java:115: illegal start of expression
    private static double totalWeight(double []singleRow){
    ^

Band.java:115: illegal start of expression
    private static double totalWeight(double []singleRow){
            ^

Band.java:115: ';' expected
    private static double totalWeight(double []singleRow){
                  ^

Band.java:115: '.class' expected
    private static double totalWeight(double []singleRow){
                                               ^

Band.java:115: ';' expected
    private static double totalWeight(double []singleRow){
                                                        ^

Band.java:123: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
18 errors
```

And here is my code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    //=============================================================================                                                                                    
    public class Band {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                    
        private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                    
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int numberRows;
            double [][] positions;
            double total;
            int numberPositions;

            System.out.println("Welcome to Band of the Hour");
            System.out.println("Please enter number of rows: ");
            numberRows = keyboard.nextInt();
            while (numberRows < 0 && numberRows > 10) {
                System.out.println("Out of range, try again: ");
                numberRows = keyboard.nextInt();
            }

        positions = new int[numberRows][];

        for (int index=0; index<numberRows; index++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter number of positions in row " + (char)(rowNumber + (int)'A') + " : ");
        numberPositions = keyboard.nextInt();
        while (numberPositions < 1 && numberPositions > 8) {
            System.out.println("Out of range, try again: ");
            }
        positions = new double[numberRows][numberPositions];
        }
        for(int i=0; i < positions.length; i++) {
          for(int j=0; j< positions[i].length; j++) {
                positions[i][j] = 0.0;
        }

        calculate(numberRows, positions, rowNumber, total);

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                    
    private static void calculate (int numberRows, double[][] positions, int[] rowNumber, double total) {
       char operation;
        int rowLetter;
        int positionNumber;
        double weight;

        do {
        System.out.println("(A)dd, (R)emove, (P)rint,           e(X)it : ");
        operation = keyboard.next().toUpper().charAt(0);
        switch (operation) {
                   case 'A':
            System.out.println("Please enter row letter :");
            rowLetter = (int)keyboard.next().toUpper().charAt(0)-'A';
                if (rowLetter < numberRows) {
                                System.out.println("Please enter position number (1 to" + positions[rowNumber].length + ")      :");
                                positionNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
                                        if (positionNumber >= 1 && positionNumber <= positions[rowNumber].length) {
                                        System.out.println("Please enter weight (45.0 to 200.0)");
                                        weight = keyboard.nextDouble();
                                                 if (weight >= 45.0 && weight <= 200.0) {
                                                         if (total <= 100 * positions[rowNumber].length) {
                                                                if (0 = positions[rowNumber][positionNumber]) {
                                                                weight = positions[rowNumber][positionNumber];
                                                                System.out.println("****** Musician added.");
                                                                } else {
                                                                System.out.println("There is already a musician there.      :");
                                                                }
                                                        } else {
                                                        System.out.println("That would exceed the row weight limit    :");
                                                        }
                                                 } else {
                                                 System.out.println("ERROR: Out of range, try again      :");
                                                 }
                                        } else {
                                        System.out.println("Out of range, try again");
                                        weight = keyboard.nextDouble();
                                          if (weight >= 45.0 && weight <= 200) {
                                          weight = positions[rowNumber][positionNumber];
                                          } else {
                                          System.out.println("Out of range, try again");
                                          weight = keyboard.nextDouble();} else {
                                System.out.println("Out of range, try again     :");
                                positionNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
                                }
                }
                        break;
                   case 'R':    
                       System.out.println("Please enter row letter :");
                            rowLetter = (int)keyboard.next().toUpper().charAt(0)-'A';
                                    if (rowLetter < numberRows) {
                                    System.out.println("Please enter position number (1 to" + positions[rowNumber].length + ")      :");
                                    positionNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
                                            if (positions[rowNumber][positionNumber] =! 0) {
                                            positions[rowNumber][positionNumber] = 0;
                                            System.out.println("****** Musician removed.");
                                            } else {
                                            System.out.println("That position is vacant             :");
                                            }
                                     } else {
                                    System.out.println("Out of range, try again     :");
                                    }
                            break;
                       case 'P':
                            System.out.printf("%5d ", positions[rowNumber][positionNumber]);
                            break;
                       default: System.out.println("Out of range, try again");
                       }
            } while (operation != 'X');
        }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                    
        private static double totalWeight(double []singleRow){
            int index;
            double total = 0.0;
            for(index = 0; index < singleRow.length; index++){
                    total = total + singleRow[index];
            }
            return total;
    }
    }
    //=============================================================================
```

Comment: You need to learn how to let you IDE format your source code. All popular IDE's can do that for you. Then it's much easier to see where you have a problem, because the braces will be properly indented.

Comment: Your code is so incredibly full of errors it's impossible to find out where to start. You're assigning doubles to ints, using variables that don't exist, calling methods that don't exit, not closing braces, using int[] as an int, trying to assign to constants, etc. I suggest you start with a small program, make it free of errors, and then move onto something bigger.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a close paren. You might find it easier to work with an IDE to make these sorts of things convenient.

Comment: where can i add the close parentheses? at the end?

Comment: I added a parenthesis at the end of the program and it fixed my last error only

Answer (score 0):

The error on line 85 is pretty self-explanatory: "else without if". Line 85 is the closing bracket of an `else` block starting on line 82. The problem with this `else` block is that it does not follow an `if` statement block:

```
if (weight >= 45.0 && weight <= 200) { // this line's got your if...
    weight = positions[rowNumber][positionNumber];
} else { // this is fine
    System.out.println("Out of range, try again");
    weight = keyboard.nextDouble();
} else { // this is causing the problem
    System.out.println("Out of range, try again     :");
    positionNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
} // this line is where the compiler is returning the error
  // it's the end of the problematic else block
```

The "reached end of file while parsing" error means you're probably missing a closing brace (this thing: } ) at the end of your code. It's generally a good idea to use a consistent pattern of indentation. This makes it easier to spot which opening and closing braces match up with each other, as well as making it easier to see which lines are inside or outside of which loops and statement blocks. It's also a good idea to use an IDE; that can help you not only with proper formatting but can also show you which braces match up with which (for example, if you click one of the braces in Netbeans, it highlights that brace and its matching one in yellow; if it has no matching one, it highlights it in red so you can easily tell if you have one too many or one too few closing braces).

I'm not sure what's causing the "illegal start of expression" errors, but it's likely you could have perhaps missed a closing brace in the main method or a different previous method. One cause for an "illegal start of expression" error is that the compiler sees a method header inside of another method. Your method headers look fine, so I wouldn't be surprised if the other errors it's giving you on those lines will be resolved once the "illegal start of expression" errors are resolved - a single typo can sometimes result in the compiler returning several errors in the section of code where it encounters a problem.